# Embedded JSON Objects not saved in BsonRecordListField using fromJSON

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift, bson

i'm using lift-mongodb-record 2.4 to manage MongoRecords for a RESTful JSON Webservice. Everything works really good, except one issue i ran into: Embedded BsonRecordListFields are not saved automatically.

This is my test-JSON:

```
{"name":"test","control_points":[{"dx":64,"dy":97},{"dx":358,"dy":64},{"dx":211,"dy":80.5}]}
```

But printing the model through `println(Artifact.fromJSON(request.body).get)` will only print

```
class com.test.model.Artifact={name=test, control_points=}
```

these are my model classes:

```
class ControlPoint private () extends BsonRecord[ControlPoint] {
  def meta = ControlPoint
  object dx extends DoubleField(this)
  object dy extends DoubleField(this)
}

object ControlPoint extends ControlPoint with BsonMetaRecord[ControlPoint]

class Artifact private () extends MongoRecord[Artifact] with ObjectIdPk[Artifact] {
  def meta = Artifact
  object name extends StringField(this, 1024)
  object control_points extends BsonRecordListField(this,ControlPoint)
}
object Artifact extends Artifact with MongoMetaRecord[Artifact] {}
```

*why is the embedded stuff not saved? do I miss anything here?*

thanks a lot!
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out on the [lift mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/liftweb/nrKifiiEOQw) lift-json parses the number as ints because they don't have a decimal point. I just changed the fields to `IntField` and parsed all date to Integers through `parseInt` on client-side.